# How can I prevent my twin pocket doors from meeting too hard?

Tags: pocket-door

We have two pocket doors, each 36" that meet to close off a 6' entryway between our living room and our sunroom.  Both doors have stops, but the stops overlap so that when one door is out and the other door is brought out, they hit and both slide backward.

I hoped to find a magnetic "catch" or something like that, but so far I have come up dry.  Best of all would be to find a way to have each door "click" into place when fully extended.

Any ideas?

Comment: even a little bumper where they meet can reduce the bounce back

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at latch on web page http://www.johnsonhardware.com/1521.htm , when the doors are closed they latch together with out locking.